# discord buttons discord py

Tags: discord.py, discord-buttons

```
class StaffView1(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.bot = bot

    @discord.ui.button(label="▶️", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id="Staff")
    async def userprofile(self, interaction, button):
        member = self.bot.get_user(1012409057119846512)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            description=f"<@{member.id}>"
                        f"\n{member.name}",
            color=0xe67e22)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar}")
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"<@&985560526258045012>", embed=embed, view=StaffView1())
```

i used the same one for slash command and it worked dont kno why this codnt work the same

press the button bt get all kind of errors it shod edit the message with a new user

Comment: Please edit your question to; narrow down to a specific issue, and include the full error that you are getting.

Comment: ```<StaffView1 timeout=None children=1> for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.primary: 1> url=None disabled=False label='▶️' emoji=None row=None>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\csggl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "C:\Users\csggl\PycharmProjects\krypton 3\commands\staff.py", line 18, in userprofile
    description=f"<@{member.id}>"
                     ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'```

Comment: when i press the button

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
member = interaction.guild.get_member(1012409057119846512)
```

Comment: I did exactly that but Tks Anyways and it worked